# Statistics with series and probability with infinitesimals

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics, infinitesimals

community. My name is Henry, and I enjoy mathematics. This is my first question. I have a good understanding of Algebra, and a general understanding of many things that go with it. However, in regard to statistics as well as probability (the more challenging stuff) I am lost, and a bit discouraged because I wish for this to me a strong suit of mine. If anybody would be willing, can you give me a general understanding for infinite series and their relation to probability and statistics, as well as the different infinitesimal series. For example, things like eulers number I understand, and have even memorized some of the digits. However, it's relation to log odds and other odds? It would be useful to know this, as well as many other things in this area involving the same thinking process. Thanks!

Comment: Infinite sequences and series arise in probability and statistics all the time, and from the very beginning.  The key basic results of probability (LLN, Central Limit Theorem) assert the limits of certain infinite sequences.

Probabilities are introduced in the first place as the *limits* (here it comes:) of the infinite sequences of statistical relative frequencies.   If these sequences do not converge, probability theory is not applicable to the phenomenon at hand.

The latter part of this video gives a brief overview of the LLN:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvqkIddRWs0

Comment: Thank you! Also not sure why I tagged abstract algebra. Must've been a typo.